# Branch feature is ahead of origin by X commits after merge dev

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-commit, git-pull

Let's say I'm on featureOne, someone else is on featureTwo and there is a dev branch. Both of us merge our work into dev. I now want to grab the dev branch and merge into featureOne so I can grab the changes from featureTwo as well and continue my work.

So I do

```
git switch develop
git pull
git switch featureOne
git merge develop
```

Why does it say after "Your branch is ahead of origin/featureOne by 13 commits"
"nothing to commit, working tree clean".

When I haven't done any further work? Nor has dev been updated. Shouldn't it just be fast forwarding?

I don't want the 13 commit history in the history of featureOne if it's related to featureTwo.

Comment: That is agains the **remote** `featureOne` branch. If you do not push into it, it will get further and further away from your **local** `featureOne`.

Comment: @eftshift0 Perhaps more helpful to say that the local will get further and further away from the remote (as the local is the one where work is being added).

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, you did do work.  You merged `develop` into your `featureOne` branch.  The 13 commits that you are ahead by are the new commits that got added your feature branch that weren't there before.

So now your local copy of `featureOne` contains 13 commits that aren't on the remote `featureOne` branch (aka `origin/featureOne`).  So you need to push in order to update the remote with these new commits.

Note: if it also says you are behind that means that the remote has commits that your local doesn't.

Comment: But won't those put those 13 commits now in the featureOne history? Wouldn't I want to avoid putting it in the history, since those changes are unrelated to the feature.

Comment: Yes, and that's fine.  I wouldn't worry that much about the history in that regard, when you merge in `develop` you are getting changes unrelated to your feature and if you need something from the other feature branch then the changes are related to the development of your feature.  While you could use a branch's history as a record of work for a feature, I don't think that you should do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not quite clear in your mind on what a merge is.

- Suppose the `merge` command results in a true merge. A true merge *makes a new commit on your branch* — a merge commit. Since that happened on your local machine only (where you did that merge), you now have a commit that the remote machine has never heard of before — the merge commit.
- Suppose the `merge` command results in a fast-forward. A fast-forward *adds commits on your branch* — the commits from the branch being merged in. Since that happened on your local machine only (where you did that merge), your now have commits on this branch that the remote machine doesn't have on this branch.

So either way, the result of a true merge is *always* going to be commits that you have that the remote doesn't.
That's what Git is reporting to you. It's not an issue, so don't worry about it. When you `git push` this branch, it will all get evened up again.

Comment: This sounds like to me a true merge is where all the 13 commits are packaged as one merge commit in the history, where the fast forward is each individual commit. I would want to avoid each 13 commit in the featureOne history as they're regarding featureTwo, no?

Comment: No, that is not what a true merge is. Perhaps you ought to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/